# How can I intercept calls to python's "magic" methods in new style classes?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to intercept calls to python's double underscore magic methods in new style classes. This is a trivial example but it show's the intent:

```
class ShowMeList(object):
    def __init__(self, it):
        self._data = list(it)

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        attr = object.__getattribute__(self._data, name)
        if callable(attr):
            def wrapper(*a, **kw):
                print "before the call"
                result = attr(*a, **kw)
                print "after the call"
                return result
            return wrapper
        return attr
```

If I use that proxy object around list I get the expected behavior for non-magic methods but my wrapper function is never called for magic methods.

```
>>> l = ShowMeList(range(8))

>>> l #call to __repr__
<__main__.ShowMeList object at 0x9640eac>

>>> l.append(9)
before the call
after the call

>> len(l._data)
9
```

If I don't inherit from object (first line `class ShowMeList:`) everything works as expected:

```
>>> l = ShowMeList(range(8))

>>> l #call to __repr__
before the call
after the call
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

>>> l.append(9)
before the call
after the call

>> len(l._data)
9
```

How do I accomplish this intercept with new style classes?

Comment: What are you really trying to do by intercepting the double-underscore methods? Or is it just for curiosity?

Comment: I always keep a list of all magic methods here: https://github.com/niccokunzmann/wwp/blob/6df6d7f60893a23dc84a32ba244b31120b1241a9/magicMethods.py (generated. so it works for python 2 and 3)

Comment: Actually it appears what you want to do is intercept calls to the magic methods of _instances_ of a new style class -- it's still a good question IMHO, however.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

For performance reasons, Python always looks in the class (and parent classes') `__dict__` for magic methods and does not use the normal attribute lookup mechanism. A workaround is to use a metaclass to automatically add proxies for magic methods at the time of class creation; I've used this technique to avoid having to write boilerplate call-through methods for wrapper classes, for example.

```
class Wrapper(object):
    """Wrapper class that provides proxy access to some internal instance."""

    __wraps__  = None
    __ignore__ = "class mro new init setattr getattr getattribute"

    def __init__(self, obj):
        if self.__wraps__ is None:
            raise TypeError("base class Wrapper may not be instantiated")
        elif isinstance(obj, self.__wraps__):
            self._obj = obj
        else:
            raise ValueError("wrapped object must be of %s" % self.__wraps__)

    # provide proxy access to regular attributes of wrapped object
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return getattr(self._obj, name)
    
    # create proxies for wrapped object's double-underscore attributes
    class __metaclass__(type):
        def __init__(cls, name, bases, dct):

            def make_proxy(name):
                def proxy(self, *args):
                    return getattr(self._obj, name)
                return proxy

            type.__init__(cls, name, bases, dct)
            if cls.__wraps__:
                ignore = set("__%s__" % n for n in cls.__ignore__.split())
                for name in dir(cls.__wraps__):
                    if name.startswith("__"):
                        if name not in ignore and name not in dct:
                            setattr(cls, name, property(make_proxy(name)))
```

Usage:

```
class DictWrapper(Wrapper):
    __wraps__ = dict

wrapped_dict = DictWrapper(dict(a=1, b=2, c=3))

# make sure it worked....
assert "b" in wrapped_dict                        # __contains__
assert wrapped_dict == dict(a=1, b=2, c=3)        # __eq__
assert "'a': 1" in str(wrapped_dict)              # __str__
assert wrapped_dict.__doc__.startswith("dict()")  # __doc__
```

Comment: @kindall I removed what looked like an orphaned line of code, but you might want to double-check that your example hasn't lost intended functionality.

Comment: Do you see any problem with doing `ignore.update(dct)` prior to looping through `dir()` and so condensing the last two `if` statements into one? Feels cleaner to me but maybe there are unintended consequences that I in my inexperience haven't anticipated.

Comment: On Python 3.8 I'm finding this example doesn't actually work as is.

Comment: I've been struggling to create a proper wrapper class.  This answer solved my issue entirely and with much less code than I originally thought would be necessary.

Comment: In Python 3 you need to move the metaclass out of the class definition and pass it in to the class declaration.

Answer (score 6):

Using `__getattr__` and `__getattribute__` are the last resources of a class to respond to getting an attribute.

Consider the following:

```
>>> class C:
    x = 1
    def __init__(self):
        self.y = 2
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        print(attr)

>>> c = C()
>>> c.x
1
>>> c.y
2
>>> c.z
z
```

The `__getattr__` method is only called when nothing else works (It will not work on operators, and you can read about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8637254/intercept-operator-lookup-on-metaclass)).

On your example, the `__repr__` and many other magic methods are already defined in the  `object` class.

One thing can be done, thought, and it is to define those magic methods and make then call the `__getattr__` method. Check this other question by me and its answers ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8637254/intercept-operator-lookup-on-metaclass)) to see some code doing that.

Answer (score 4):

As of the answers to [Asymmetric behavior for __getattr__, newstyle vs oldstyle classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3415816/asymmetric-behavior-for-getattr-newstyle-vs-oldstyle-classes) (see also the [Python docs](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#new-style-special-lookup)), modifying access to "magic" methods with `__getattr__` or `__getattribute__` is just not possible with new-style classes. This restriction makes the interpreter much faster.

Comment: Thanks. I found [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3416058/531516) helpful in fleshing out your answer.

Answer (score -1):

Cut and copy from the documentation:

For old-style classes, special methods are always looked up in exactly the same way as any other method or attribute.

For new-style classes, implicit invocations of special methods are only guaranteed to work correctly if defined on an object’s type, not in the object’s instance dictionary.

Comment: This answer is 100% correct while explaining nothing and being completely unhelpful. Sorry.

Comment: An old Bell Labs joke: a pilot lost in a thick fog sees an office building, shouts out "where am I ?", gets the answer "in an airplane", and touches down in ... Allentown. How did he know ? "The answer is 100% correct ..."