# Why can I override '__setattr__' but not assign it in the __init__ method?

Tags: python, python-2.7

E.g.

```
def __setattr__(self, name, value):
    ...
```

works fine, however:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.__setattr__ = foo
```

doesn't seem to achieve anything in that foo is never called.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Starting point: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9057669/how-can-i-intercept-calls-to-pythons-magic-methods-in-new-style-classes

Comment: `__setattr__` is looked up on the class, not on the instance.

Answer (score 1):

`__setattr__` uses the class method, not the instance method. Examine the output of the following code:

Code:

```
def func(*args):
    print "--Func--"
    print args

class A():
    def __setattr__(*args):
        print "--SetAttr--"
        print args


a = A()

print "a.x = 10"
a.x = 10
print

A.__setattr__ = func

print "a.y = 20"
a.y = 20
print
```

Output:

```
a.x = 10
--SetAttr--
(<__main__.A instance at 0x2cb120>, 'x', 10)

a.y = 20
--Func--
(<__main__.A instance at 0x2cb120>, 'y', 20)
```

You could write your code such that the class method calls an instance method:

```
class C():
    def __init__(self, setattr):
        #Must access in this way since we overwrote __setattr__ already
        self.__dict__['setattr_func'] = setattr

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        self.setattr_func(name, value)
```