# Wrap an object into a derived class

Tags: python, python-2.7, inheritance

Suppose I have a class A coming from a third-party library (FYI it is numpy.matrix). I want to expand its public interface with a wrapper class B.

```
class B(A):
    def myMethod(self,arg):
        return 'spam'
```

And also, I want to create B objects from A object. Since B will not hold any more attribute, I just really want to return the A object, with the B behavior:

```
class B(A):
    def __new__(cls,a): # type(a)==A
        return a.castTo(B) # pseudo-code
```

Is there a way to do it in python ?

Similarily, is there a way to cast B objects to A objects ?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25394550/adding-methods-to-an-existing-class-instance-or-how-to-subclass-an-instance

Comment: @NickT: Thank you. It seems to be sooo complicated. Isn't the language supporting this kind of basic OOP stuff ? In C++ it would be a short one-liner. Same in ruby (AFAIK). Or Python does not work this way ? I am confused...

Comment: Seems like you should be able to use a decorator: http://thecodeship.com/patterns/guide-to-python-function-decorators/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your class B's `__new__` needs to call A's `__new__`. Here's a brief demo using the built-in `list` class.

```
class mylist(list):
    def __new__(cls, obj=None):
        return list.__new__(cls, obj)

    def mymethod(self, msg):
        print msg, id(self)


def main():
    a = mylist('abc')
    print a, id(a)
    a.mymethod('hello')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

If you just want to add a simple *function* to an instance of an existing class, you can do this sort of thing.

```
class A(object):
    pass

def silly(arg=None):
    print 'This is silly', arg

b = A()
b.my = silly
b.my()
```

Note that `b.my` it just a function, not a method, so it does **not** get passed self when you call it. But you can pass it "by hand" by doing `b.my(b)`

---

**Edit**

As an alternative to writing `list.__new__(cls, obj)`, you can call the `super()` function:

```
def __new__(cls, obj=None):
    return super(mylist, cls).__new__(cls, obj)
```

But in most cases using the base class name is clearer and shorter. I guess there *might* be a reason to prefer `super()`, but I'm not enough of an expert on this stuff to say. :)

Comment: Thank you, the first part is the answer I expected. I wasn't able to find anything on the internet. I used __new_ to return [], not list.__new__(cls, obj), so I ended up with a base class object.

Comment: I learned about that syntax from Guido, in [the docs](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.2.3/descrintro#__new__), but it's not something I've used often.

Comment: Note that the `super()` calling syntax has been simplified in Python 3. https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?super#super