# Python: How to extend a huge class with minimum lines of code?

Tags: python, arrays, class, inheritance, numpy

### Original problem description

The problem arises when I implement some machine learning algorithm with `numpy`. I want some new class `ludmo` which **works the same as** `numpy.ndarray`, but with a few more properties. For example, with a new property `ludmo.foo`. I've tried several methods below, but none is satisfactory.

### 1. Wrapper

First I created a wrapper class for `numpy.ndarray`, as

```
import numpy as np

class ludmo(object):
    def __init__(self)
        self.foo = None
        self.data = np.array([])
```

But when I use some function (in `scikit-learn` which I cannot modify) to manipulate a list of `np.ndarray` instance, I have to first extract all `data` field of each `ludmo` object and collect them into a list. After that the list is sorted and I lost the correspondence between the `data` and original `ludmo` objects.

### 2. Inheritance

Then I tried to make `ludmo` a subclass of `numpy.ndarray`, as

```
import numpy as np

class ludmo(np.ndarray):
    def __init__(self, shape, dtype=float, buffer=None, offset=0, strides=None, order=None)
        super().__init__(shape, dtype, buffer, offset, strides, order)
        self.foo = None
```

But another problem arises then: the most common way to create a `numpy.ndarray` object is `numpy.array(some_list)`, which returns a `numpy.ndarray` object, and I have to convert it to a `ludmo` object. But till now I found no good way to do this; simply changing the `__class__` attribute will result in an error.

I'm new to Python and numpy, so there must be some elegant way that I don't know. Any advice is appreciated.

It's better if anyone can give an generic solution, which not only applies to the `numpy.ndarray` class but also all kinds of classes.

Comment: There's [a page in the numpy docs about that](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.subclassing.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you ask about a generic solution, here's a generic wrapper class that you can use: (from http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577555-object-wrapper-class/ )

```
class Wrapper(object):
    '''
    Object wrapper class.
    This a wrapper for objects. It is initialiesed with the object to wrap
    and then proxies the unhandled getattribute methods to it.
    Other classes are to inherit from it.
    '''
    def __init__(self, obj):
        '''
        Wrapper constructor.
        @param obj: object to wrap
        '''
        # wrap the object
        self._wrapped_obj = obj

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        # see if this object has attr
        # NOTE do not use hasattr, it goes into
        # infinite recurrsion
        if attr in self.__dict__:
            # this object has it
            return getattr(self, attr)
        # proxy to the wrapped object
        return getattr(self._wrapped_obj, attr)
```

the way this works is:

when e.g. skicit would call ludmo.data python actually calls
`ludmo.__getattribute__('data')`
if ludmo doesn't have the 'data' attribute, python will call
`ludmo.__getattr__('data')`

by overridding the `__getattr__` function you intercept this call, check if your ludmo has the `data` attribute (again, you could get into recursion otherwise), and send the call to your internal object. So you should have covered every possible call to your internal numpy object.

**update**:
You would also have to implement `__setattr__` the same way, or you would get this

```
>>> class bla(object):
...  def __init__(self):
...   self.a = 1
...  def foo(self):
...   print self.a
...
>>> d = Wrapper(bla())
>>> d.a
1
>>> d.foo()
1
>>> d.a = 2
>>> d.a
2
>>> d.foo()
1
```

and you probably also want to set a new metaclass that intercepts calls to magic functions of new style classes (for full class see https://github.com/hpcugent/vsc-base/blob/master/lib/vsc/utils/wrapper.py 
for info see [How can I intercept calls to python's "magic" methods in new style classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9057669/how-can-i-intercept-calls-to-pythons-magic-methods-in-new-style-classes)
)
however, this is only needed if you still want to be able to access `x.__name__` or `x.__file__` and get the magic attribute from the wrapped class, and not your class.

```
# create proxies for wrapped object's double-underscore attributes
    class __metaclass__(type):
        def __init__(cls, name, bases, dct):

            def make_proxy(name):
                def proxy(self, *args):
                    return getattr(self._obj, name)
                return proxy

            type.__init__(cls, name, bases, dct)
            if cls.__wraps__:
                ignore = set("__%s__" % n for n in cls.__ignore__.split())
                for name in dir(cls.__wraps__):
                    if name.startswith("__"):
                        if name not in ignore and name not in dct:
                            setattr(cls, name, property(make_proxy(name)))
```

Comment: This solution is fine when I only access `ludmo.data` but not modify it. I referred to the documentation and it said that, when I modify an non-exist field python would silently create a new one. So when I write `ludmo.data = 2`, does python set `ludmo.obj.data` to 2 or it just create a new field `ludmo.data`? Maybe I should define `__setattr__` as well?

Comment: I would accept your answer, though I still can't  understand how the last piece of code (the `__metaclass__`) got to work. If you could explain a bit more about it or give a reference link, that would be better.

Answer (score 4):

As [explained in the docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.subclassing.html) you could add your own methods to `np.ndarray` doing:

```
import numpy as np

class Ludmo(np.ndarray): 
    def sumcols(self):
        return self.sum(axis=1)

    def sumrows(self):
        return self.sum(axis=0)

    def randomize(self):
        self[:] = np.random.rand(*self.shape)
```

and then creating the instances using [the `np.ndarray.view()` method](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.view.html#numpy-ndarray-view):

```
a = np.random.rand(4,5).view(Ludmo)
```

And use the `__array_finalize__()` method to define new attributes:

```
def __array_finalize__(self, arr):
    self.foo = 'foo'
```